# Aws lambda binary file EACCES error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I got `Error: spawn EACCES` error at the following line when I tried to execute this in aws lambda.

```
var zip = childProcess.spawn('zip', [
        '-r',
        job.destination.name,
        './'
    ], {
        cwd: temporaryDirectoryPath
    });
```

I have a binary file 'zip'.

Full error trace:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
at createCompressedFile (/var/task/index.js:141:32)
at /var/task/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
at iterate (/var/task/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
at /var/task/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
at /var/task/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
at /var/task/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
at /var/task/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by `cwd : temporaryDirectoryPath`, when the user your process is running as doesn't have access to `temporaryDirectoryPath`.

Comment: I create that directory in every instance with this line `var mkdir = childProcess.spawn('mkdir', [
            temporaryDirectoryPath
        ], {
            cwd: __dirname
        });`

Comment: And `temporaryDirectoryPath = path.join('/tmp', context.awsRequestId);`

Comment: Do you check for errors when that directory is created? FWIW, you can use [`fs.mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback) instead of spawning a child process to call `mkdir`.

Comment: Yeah. I have a console.log for that. and the exit code is 0.

Comment: Can you check and see if `process.chdir(temporaryDirectoryPath)` works?

Comment: I got undefined in `console.log` for `process.chdir(temporaryDirectoryPath)`

Comment: The undefined isn't a problem, it was just for testing to see if `cwd` could be set to `temporaryDirectoryPath`, which it can. So that's not the problem. Another possible reason is that the `zip` executable doesn't have the correct permissions (no executable bits set). How do you transfer it to Lambda?

Comment: By uploading as a zip file. Before uploading I did `chmod 777 *` too.

Comment: I don't know exactly how Lambda works, but if you know the full path to the `zip` executable, you could try to use [`fs.chmod()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmod_path_mode_callback) to give it executable permissions (or use [`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) to check what they are).

Comment: `Error: EROFS: read-only file system, chmod 'zip'` I got this error

Comment: Hmm okay, that's a bit too Lambda-specific for me :(

Comment: Please check the owner and permission on the folder

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it worked for me. So all errors like EACCES, ENOEN...  has gone.

```
child_process.spawnSync('mybinary', [], {
  shell: true
})
```